# Using Cauchy-Schwarz to Prove Absolute Convergence

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, inequality, convergence-divergence

This is a question from a book I'm self-studying, and I have no idea where to start. I would appreciate hints rather than full answers.

Let $V$ consist of all infinite sequences $\{x_n\}$ of real numbers for which the series $\sum x_n^2$ converges. If $x=\{x_n\}$ and $y=\{y_n\}$ are two elements of $V$, prove that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x_n y_n
$$
converges absolutely.

The hint given in the book is: use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to estimate the sum $\sum_{n=1}^m |x_n y_n|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $m$, then by C-S
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{m} |x_i y_i| &\leq (\sum_{i=1}^{m} |x_i|^2 ) ^{1/2} (\sum_{i=1}^{m} |y_i|^2)^{1/2} \\
&\leq (\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i|^2 ) ^{1/2} (\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |y_i|^2)^{1/2}
\end{align}

Taking $\sup$ with respect to $m$ and noticing that $\sup_{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m} |x_i y_i|=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |x_i y_i|$ we conclude.

Comment: Doesn't C-S say $|\sum x_i y_i|$ rather than $\sum |x_i y_i|$?

Comment: @MGA if the vector is $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_m)$ here my vector is $(|x_1|,|x_2|,\cdots,|x_m|)$

Comment: I understand now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

$\sum |x_ny_n| \le (\sum x_n^2)^{1/2}(\sum y_n^2)^{1/2}$ - Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: I don't understand how this is Cauchy-Schwarz. I thought it only applies to inner products, and this is not an inner product.

Comment: @MGA why would it not be an inner product? Have you checked if any condition for inner product is violated?

Comment: @MGA What do you think is an inner product?

Comment: Ah okay. If I look at it as an inner product, which it is (I've checked), I can say $|\sum x_n y_n| \leq \sum |x_n y_n|$, and then use Cauchy-Schwarz, right?

Comment: Absolute convergence definition is the sums of the absolute value converges...

Comment: What bothers me is the circular logic. We're treating it as an inner product to apply Cauchy Schwarz, but it can't be an inner product if it doesn't converge.